# Execute a Function after all slideDowns/slideUps are completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery function which runs jQuery slideUp/slideDown.

There are two slide Options which would get executed at a time.

Here's the code:

```
  updateView: function(){
    var falseItems = jQuery(".cjs-milestone-task-container-false");
    var trueItems = jQuery(".cjs-milestone-task-container-true");
    var linkObject = jQuery("#cjs_milestones_see_all");
    if(jQuery(MentoringModelMilestones.milestoneBlock).data("mode") == MentoringModelMilestones.viewStatus){
      linkObject.html(linkObject.data("collapsed"));
      linkObject.addClass("collapsed");
      **falseItems.slideUp();**
      MentoringModelMilestones.toggleSeeAll(falseItems.length == 0);
    }
    else{
      linkObject.html(linkObject.data("expanded"));
      linkObject.removeClass("collapsed");
      **falseItems.slideDown();**
      MentoringModelMilestones.toggleSeeAll(trueItems.length == 0);
    }
    **trueItems.slideDown();**
  },
```

I need to call this function after the slideUp/slideDown are completed:

```
  addMergeTop: function(){
    jQuery(MentoringModelMilestones.milestoneBlock).find(".cjs_milestone_container").addClass('merge-top');
    jQuery(MentoringModelMilestones.milestoneBlock).find(".cjs_milestone_container:visible").first().removeClass('merge-top');
  },
```

Passing this as a function to slideUp/slideDown doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to chain the calls to `slideUp` and `slideDown`:

```
falseItems.slideUp(400 /* duration */, function() {
    trueItems.slideDown(400, function() {
        /* perform actions that should be done after both animations complete */
        console.log("all animations done");
    });
});
```

You'll need to do something similar for both cases of the `if/else`.

Note that this will perform one operation *after* the other. If you want **both operations to occur simultaneously** (or if you don't want to merge these two calls), then you'll need to do something hackier to maintain shared state. For example:

```
function slideAll() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#falseItems").slideUp("slow" /* duration */ , function() {
        if (2 === ++count) {
            alert("all done");
        }
    });
    $("#trueItems").slideDown("slow", function() {
        if (2 === ++count) {
            alert("all done");
        }
    });
}

slideAll();
```

You don't have to do all of this in one `slideAll` function, but (however you do it) you *do* need to keep track of which animations have finished before you execute any code that relies on both.

See the second example in action:

- http://jsfiddle.net/EKJGx/

Comment: Is that the only way possible. I was hoping of a solution without merging my slideUp and slideDown calls.

Comment: An alternative is to maintain some state. See my updated answer.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You need to pass a *reference* to a function in the second argument to `slideUp/Down`. Don't *call* a function there.

Comment: Even this hack doesn't work. The function gets completed without count reaching 2. I need to execute something inside this function by making it reach 2.

Comment: It *does* work. See the linked fiddle :) Seriously, though, if it's still failing then you have some other issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hack and jsfiddle. It'll help me debug.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the callback function as a second parameter of your slideUp() or slideDown().

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mKYd4/)

```
function doSlide(){
  $('.slider').slideUp(1000,function(){
      alert('done sliding');
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this. I am giving only a logic you can modify it to your needs

```
//place this at top
var falseItemsComplete = trueItems = false;

//modify below things in your code
falseItems.slideUp('fast', function() {
  falseItemsComplete  = true;//slideup for falseItems completed
  checkCompletedStatus();
});

trueItems.slideDown('fast', function() {
  trueItemsComplete  = true;//slideup for trueItems completed
  checkCompletedStatus();
});

function checkCompletedStatus(){
  if(falseItemsComplete  && trueItemsComplete ){
     //both animations complete
     alert(1)
  }
}
```